# How to draw a coin (a grey circle with black text centered on it) in iOS?

Tags: ios

I understand that the question might sound too simple, but only after struggling for several hours with this simple thing am I posting this here. (Yup, I am new to custom drawing and iOS dev in general).

I am trying to draw a coin. It is a gray circle with some text centered on it.

What I have tried so far:

```
CGFloat *radius = 30;
CGPoint center = self.view.center;
CGRect someFrame = CGRectMake(center.x - radius, center.y - radius,
                              2 * radius, 2 * radius);
UIView *circularView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
circularView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];


UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
label.text = @"5";
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

[circularView addSubview:label];

circularView.clipsToBounds = YES;
circularView.layer.cornerRadius = radius;

[self.view addSubview:circularView];
```

Have tried this and other variants. But none of it is working. The label is not appearing, and the view is not being drawn in the center of the view as expected in landscape mode.

Is there any better way to do this, using CALayer or Quartz or Core Graphics? As I said, I am new to this.

Comment: override drawRect and use Quartz core lib for this. Would be much simpler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first:

```
CGFloat *radius = 30;
```

That...shouldn't really even compile. Or at least there should be one mean warning. That's not what you want. You want to say this:

```
CGFloat radius = 30;
```

That asterisk is going to, just, that's bad. You'll know when you want to use a pointer to a primitive value and this just ain't one o' those times.

---

With that outta the way, you're on the right track, but it looks like you have a misunderstanding about coordinate spaces.

You initialize the circle with the frame `someFrame`. This is a frame that makes sense in the coordinate space of `self.view`, which is good, because that's where you're adding it (mostly, see side note below).

But then you set the label's `frame` to the same thing. Which might be okay, except that you're adding it to the `circularView` -- not to `self.view`. Which means that the frame that made sense as a frame for a child of `self.view` suddenly doesn't make very much sense at all. What you really want is just the following:

```
// The label will take up the whole bounds of the circle view.
// Labels automatically center their text vertically.
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:circularView.bounds];
// Center the text in the label horizontally.
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
// Make it so that the label's frame is tied to the bounds of
// the circular view, so that if its size changes in the future
// the label will still look right.
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

The problem that you have now is that label is *way off somewhere else*, sticking off the edge of `circularView` (and thus getting clipped) because `someFrame` doesn't make sense in `circularView`'s coordinate space.

---

Side note:

This won't work well if `self.view.frame.origin` isn't `CGPointZero`. It usually is, but what you really want is the center of the view's *`bounds`*, not the center of the view's `frame`. `self.view.center` gives you a point in the coordinate space of `self.view.superview`. It just so happens that this will appear to work as long as `self.view.frame.origin` is `{0, 0}`, but to be more technically correct, you should say:

```
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds),
                             CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));
```

You can also make `circularView` *remain* in the center of the view even as the view's bounds change (for example, if you rotate the device), with the following:

```
circularView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Yes, typing out `autoresizingMask`s manually is the worst thing ever, but it's worth it in the long run (actually, in the long run, you'll probably go crazy and make a shorter helper method like me...).

Comment: First of all, thanks for this wonderful answer! I really appreciate the time you took to explain all the stuff in the very way I needed. 

I tried it out and now it works great! 

Jus wondering how to redraw the circularView and the label when the device is rotated?

Comment: @Roboris you don't need to redraw it; views will automatically redraw their subviews when they need to. I added a note at the very bottom about keeping `circularView` centered, though.

Comment: ...you do need to worry about manually redrawing if you are writing a custom `drawRect:`, but for something this simple you don't need to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the autoresizing tip. It worked! Actually I intend to push this off into its own class and then use instances of it in a simple game. So it needs to be easily animatable. Hence the drawing of the label on top of it as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the origin of the label's frame. When you add the label to the background view, the origin of its frame is relative to its superview.
So it would be something like `CGRectMake(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius)` for the background view, `CGRectMake(0, 0, 2 * radius, 2 * radius)` for the label.
Besides that, you can skip the background view and tint the UILabel's background color.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you are creating a frame for the view container (circularView) with some non zero x and y.  Then you are creating a label and giving it the same frame (with non zero x and y).  Then you add the label to the container view.  The label's x and y will be relative to the container view's x and y (offset, not centered).  If you want the label and the container to share the same location on screen then change it to this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: circularView.bounds];
```

Another problem is with how simple you are making this you could do it all with the label (ignore the container view).

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
label.text = @"5";
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
label.clipsToBounds = YES;
label.layer.cornerRadius = radius;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
]self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: I fixed the first issue you mentioned. But about the second thing you mentioed, if I choose your style, wouldn't it show the "circular"View behind the circular label?